# Netlogo World coordinates

Tags: netlogo

can I set the min/max pxcor and pycor in Netlogo interface from code?  Want to choose a state, and then use its min/max lat/long to set the display so it fills up the whole world.  I guess the alternative is to make the world wide enough and high enough for the biggest state and then adjust all lat/long values to fit that.  I'm only looking at lower 48 states since Alaska is huge and Hawaii spread out, but still makes Rhode Island teeny next to Texas.

Answer (score 3):

Sure. Just take a look at the [`resize-world`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#resize-world) primitive.

Just be aware that:

> As a side effect, all turtles and links die, and the existing patch grid is discarded and new patches created.